# Google Sheets - Is there a way to filter values but keep them in the respective rows they came from?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking for a way to filter values based on another column but keep them in the same rows they came from. Here's an example I created manually of the correct output:
[image]

The goal here is to have a formula (or maybe 3 separate filter formulas) such that the constants can be sorted based on sample number but retain the original rows they came from so that they keep their associated dates. I figure I can use something like `=FILTER(B2:B,C2:C="Sample1")` to fill in column G, but that doesn't retain the rows properly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="Sample1",B2:B,))
```

We are essentially saying: if C2:C is equal to "Sample1" return the corresponding value in B2:B, otherwise, leave the cell blank.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried something very similar to this before, maybe I just had my columns mixed up. Anyway, thanks a ton! This works exactly the way I needed it to.